# shell: undo the count from `uniq -c`

Tags: uniq

Is there a good way to undo the `-c` option from [`uniq`](http://mdoc.su/f/uniq)?

(Sometimes it makes sense to keep the count in a saved file, but then you'd want to get rid of it for further processing.)

---

I've tried playing with [`cut`](http://mdoc.su/f/cut) `-f`, but it doesn't really work, and specifying a space separator, with `-d" "`, doesn't seem to work, either, because there'd often be a different number of spaces (depending on how big a given count is).

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /dev/fd/0 | \
sed -E "s#^[ ]*[0-9]+[ ]##g"
```